# Spring web service maven-jaxb2-plugin complex input

Tags: spring, web-services, jaxb, maven-3

I need to create a client based on WSDL.   I am using Spring 4 and Spring web service 2.2.0. Using maven-jaxb2-plugin I created classes and able to invoke web service. I am using object factory to create some objects, due to complex data type. Now I have a complex input. and I don't find appropriate methods in the generated class.

As per SOAP UI , the request body  looks like

```
<soapenv:Body>
  <zhin:ZHIN_HR_CA_EVALUATOR_SEND_RFCresponse>
    <IN_DATA>
      <IV_PERNR>4005002</IV_PERNR>
      <IT_RATERS>
        <!--1 or more repetitions:-->
        <ArrayOfIT_RATERSItem>
          <ORGTX>?</ORGTX>
          <DESIG>?</DESIG>
          <ENAME>N V S Ravi Kumar</ENAME>
          <ZCPERNRT>?</ZCPERNRT>
          <PERNR>4005001</PERNR>
          <WEIGH>?</WEIGH>
          <SEQUENCE>1St Evaluator</SEQUENCE>
        </ArrayOfIT_RATERSItem>
      </IT_RATERS>
      <IV_APCAT>1</IV_APCAT>
    </IN_DATA>
  </zhin:ZHIN_HR_CA_EVALUATOR_SEND_RFCresponse>
</soapenv:Body>
```

Now i don't find a method to set  `ArrayOfITRATERS`  but I have `getArrayOfITRATERSItem()`

```
final ObjectFactory objectFactory = new ObjectFactory();
final INDATA requestValue = objectFactory.createINDATA();
requestValue.setIVPERNR(String.valueOf(id));
requestValue.setIVAPCAT(AppConstants.CA);
final ArrayOfITRATERS value = objectFactory.createArrayOfITRATERS();
value.set .....(not found ???)        
requestValue.setITRATERS(value);
```

My autogenerated `ArrayOfITRATERS` class looks like

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "ArrayOfIT_RATERS", propOrder = {
    "arrayOfITRATERSItem"
})
public class ArrayOfITRATERS {

    @XmlElement(name = "ArrayOfIT_RATERSItem", required = true)
    protected List<ITRATERS> arrayOfITRATERSItem;

    public List<ITRATERS> getArrayOfITRATERSItem() {
        if (arrayOfITRATERSItem == null) {
            arrayOfITRATERSItem = new ArrayList<ITRATERS>();
        }
        return this.arrayOfITRATERSItem;
    }
}
```

I am not sure how to set the `ArrayOfITRATERS` 
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does

```
getArrayOfITRATERSItem().add(myITRATERS);
```

solve your problem?

JAXB XJC does not generate setters for collections by default. Just add your items to the collection returned by the getter.

Comment: I tried adding a setter method manually and it also worked. But    yours works perfectly.